# Copy/paste from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

It is a simple task, but I don't know why it is not working…

This is my code :

```
Dim chemin As String
Workbooks.Open ("Z:\ext_Workbook.xlsx") 
Sheets("produits").Activate
Sheets("produits").Range("A1:CZ500").Copy 

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets("STT").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks("ext_Workbook.xlsx").Close
```

The run stop at the line :

```
 Sheets("STT").Select
```

But I verified, and there is a sheet named **STT**, with the same spelling

Comment: A must read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: ThisWorkbook refers to the workbook running the macro(not the ext_Workbook.xlsx), I assume the STT sheet is in ext_Workbook.xlsx, correct?

Comment: **1.** `Set Wb = Workbooks.Open ("Z:\ext_Workbook.xlsx")` **2.** And then `Wb.Sheets("produits").Range("A1:CZ500").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("STT").Range("A1")`

Comment: the STT sheet is in the workbook who is running the macro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should work for you.

```
Dim SourceWBK As Workbook, DestinationWBK As Workbook

Set SourceWBK = Workbooks.Open("Z:\ext_Workbook.xlsx")
Set DestinationWBK = ThisWorkbook

SourceWBK.Worksheets("produits").Range("A1:CZ500").Copy
DestinationWBK.Worksheets("STT").Range("A1:CZ500").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
SourceWBK.Close False
```

Comment: No.. You cannot copy and paste like this. One way is to do it in the same line as I showed in the comment below the quesiton. If you want to paste it in separate line then use `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll` instead of `.Paste`

Comment: I just removed "dim chemin as String" and now it's working… some mystery come with this solution..

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Edited the Code as suggested.